# Emacs elisp default help documents

Tags: emacs

This question arose when I noticed, upon starting an emacs lisp script, that the command C-h f did not recognize the function org-table-get-field. That is to say when I type C-h f org-table-get-field, I get the [No Match] in the EchoArea. However when I run a lisp code block, I CAN get a match and information on org-table-get-field. Does anybody know what the machine is doing that all of a sudden it has access to function information it did not before I evaluate lisp code blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code defining a function or variable needs to have been loaded or otherwise evaluated, for the help commands to recognize it.

No doubt the code in question here is *autoloaded* upon your first use of some command. Once it has been loaded, `C-h f` works for your function, `org-table-get-field`. Autoloading is the magic you were wondering about.

See the Elisp manual, node [*Autoload*](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Autoload.html).

Comment: To clarify, `org-table-get-field` itself does not have an autoload defined (otherwise `C-h f` *would* know about it); but it resides in a library which is being loaded on account of something else.

Comment: @phils: Yeah, that's what I meant by "of some command" (though it could be something besides a command). Something, somewhere, causes the relevant code to be autoloaded, and that's how it becomes defined.